# Is it possible for EMI to affect power on?

Tags: boot, electrical-power, interference

I have a server that boots fine everyone in the office except for in the room I want to put it in.  When I put it in that room it won't even get to the loading Windows screen it simply gets stuck in a reboot cycle.  Other electronics have been known to fail in this room, is it possible for EMI to be causing this interference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That or the power feed in that room is so overloaded or unclean that it's spiking, causing the machine to reboot constantly.

Comment: It is theoretically possible that EMI could be doing this but very unlikely, I think you're absolutely right about the power feed :)